# glm in R, give all comparisons

Tags: r, model, regression, glm

Simple logistic regression example.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(out=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0), 
           y=rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 3))

result <-glm(out~factor(y), family = 'binomial', data=df)
summary(result)

#Call:
#glm(formula = out ~ factor(y), family = "binomial", data = df)

#Deviance Residuals: 
#    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#-1.4823  -0.9005  -0.9005   0.9005   1.4823  

#Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#(Intercept) -6.931e-01  1.225e+00  -0.566    0.571
#factor(y)B   1.386e+00  1.732e+00   0.800    0.423
#factor(y)C   3.950e-16  1.732e+00   0.000    1.000

#(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

#     Null deviance: 12.365  on 8  degrees of freedom
#Residual deviance: 11.457  on 6  degrees of freedom
#AIC: 17.457

#Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

My reference category is now A; results for B and C relative to A are given. I would also like to get the results when B and C are the reference. One can change the reference manually by using `levels =` in `factor()`; but this would require fitting 3 models. Is it possible to do this in one go? Or what would be a more efficient approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do all pairwise comparisons, you should usually also do a correction for alpha-error inflation due to multiple testing. You can easily do a Tukey test with package multcomp.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(out=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0), 
                 y=rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 3))

#y is already a factor, if not, coerce before the model fit
result <-glm(out~y, family = 'binomial', data=df)
summary(result)

library(multcomp)
comps <- glht(result, linfct = mcp(y = "Tukey"))
summary(comps)
#Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
#
#Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts
#
#
#Fit: glm(formula = out ~ y, family = "binomial", data = df)
#
#Linear Hypotheses:
#  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#B - A == 0  1.386e+00  1.732e+00     0.8    0.703
#C - A == 0  1.923e-16  1.732e+00     0.0    1.000
#C - B == 0 -1.386e+00  1.732e+00    -0.8    0.703
#(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

#letter notation often used in graphs and tables
cld(comps)
#  A   B   C 
#"a" "a" "a"
```

Comment: The "tukey" used in `multcomp::glht` doesn't refer to the Tukey test.  It just refers to the fact that your calling for all pairwise tests.